# What is the fastest way to find common tangents for two 2 degree curves?

Tags: coordinate-systems

Im having problem in many questions of this type - "Find the common tangent to the given curves". Usually the curves given are shifted standard conics.

I have two approaches for this-

Assume a line y = mx + c, substitute y in the conics, since they intersect at one point only; make the Discriminant zero and find c and m.

My other approach is using standard equations for tangents which we were taught in class.

The problem is these standard eq. Only apply for standard conics and im having problem in the rotated versions of the conics.

Please help me.

(Im new here. Please tell me if im breaking any rules)

Comment: The only "violation" is that you do not use MathJax. (https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Comment: This doesn’t even work for all “standard” conics: a vertical line cannot be represented by an equation of the form $y=my+b$.

Comment: @amd I think because of my poor representation of the question you did not understand it. I mean i suppose any line y = mx + c. If the line is vertical, ill get m= N.D.

Comment: If you start by assuming tangents of the form $y=my+b$ for the hyperbola $x^2-y^2=1$, for enxample, you won’t get an undefined slope. You will miss the vertical tangents entirely.

Comment: @amd Im not sure if i can find out tangents with just 1 eq. In terms of 'm' and 'b'. If a get one more information i thin i surely can find the vertical tangent. Correct me if im wrong please.

Comment: Use an equation of the form $ax+by+c=0$ instead. The resulting equations won’t necessarily give you a unique solution for the coefficients of this equation, but the solutions will be unique up to a non-zero scale factor, which doesn’t change the solution set of the equation of the tangent line.

Comment: @amd Thanks a lot :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One general approach to finding common tangents of a pair of conics is to solve the dual problem: compute the intersections of the dual conics.

If you represent tangent lines to a conic by equations of the form $\lambda x+\mu y+\tau = 0$, it turns out that the coefficients of these equations themselves satisfy a general conic equation. This is the *dual conic*. If you represent the original conic as a matrix equation $$\mathbf x^T C \mathbf x = 0$$ then the matrix of the dual conic is the *adjugate* of $C$. For non-degenerate conics, for which $C$ is nonsingular, you can also use $C^{-1}$.

Solving this intersection problem involves solving a cubic equation in the general case, so I encourage you to take advantage of the geometry of specific problems that you’re trying to solve in order to simplify the calculations.

---

The general conic equation $ax^2+2bxy+cy^2+2dx+2ey+f=0$ has the corresponding matrix $$C = \begin{bmatrix}a&b&d\\b&c&e\\d&e&f\end{bmatrix}.$$ Its adjugate is $$C^{\tiny\triangle} = \begin{bmatrix} cf-e^2 & de-bf & be-cd \\ de-bf & af-d^2 & bd-ae \\ be-cd & bd-ae & ac-b^2\end{bmatrix}.$$ Basically, this is the matrix of $2\times2$ submatrix determinants multiplied by $(-1)^{i+j}$, where $i$ and $j$ are the respective row and column indices. So, if the equation of a tangent line to this conic is $\lambda x+\mu y+\tau = 0$, its coefficients satisfy the equation $$\begin{bmatrix}\lambda&\mu&\tau\end{bmatrix}C^{\tiny\triangle}\begin{bmatrix}\lambda\\\mu\\\tau\end{bmatrix} = (cf-e^2)\lambda^2 + (af-d^2)\mu^2 + (ac-b^2)\tau^2 + 2(de-bf)\lambda\mu + 2(be-cd)\lambda\tau + 2(bd-ae)\mu\tau = 0.$$